# Error using Flickr photos search api: Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)

Tags: php, curl, flickr

In my app I'm doing some work to construct a query string to call through Flickr API, the result is something like this:

```
https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&api_key={MY API KEY}&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=happy%2Cdog
```

Requesting that in the browser works just fine, however, requesting the same query with curl returns an error:

```
jsonFlickrApi({"stat":"fail","code":100,"message":"Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)"})
```

Here's my curl code:

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->query);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: And you have made sure that `$this->query` contains that _exact_ same URL?

Comment: If you put the above URL string hardcoded in place of `$this->query`, what response do you get?

Comment: @misorude: yes, with a return just before the `curl_exec` line..

Comment: Does the API key contain anything that might be considered ”special characters” in a URL context maybe? Possible that your browser applies URL encoding on its own, but cURL doesn’t.

Comment: @PatrickQ it works actually! what do you think the problem is? as I've copied the url from the return value of `$this->query`?

Comment: @misorude it only contains letters and numbers

Comment: Perhaps you have a `&amp;` in there actually, which the browser will display as `&`, so it gets “transformed” into the correct character again, when you copy&paste? Do `echo htmlspecialchars($this->query);`, and check.

Comment: @misorude Yes! that was the problem, thanks man! if you want to write an answer I'll accept it..

Comment: @Al-MootasemBellah  Simply put, if the above string works, and `$this->query` doesn't, then `$this->query` does _not_ contain the above string as you claim it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works when the URL generated by your system gets copy&pasted into the browser, then something must be different.

Your debug output likely got interpreted as HTML, so if there is an erroneous `&amp;` in there somewhere instead of just an `&`, it still *looks* like an `&`, and also gets copy&pasted as `&`.

`htmlspecialchars` is always helpful in cases like this, to see the actual value, and not what the browser has interpreted it as.